Create dataframe from specific XML data in Python
I have an XML file (example shown below) that I want to have in a dataframe in Python. The issue is that the data in the XML has a specific structure and I'm having some trouble with getting the data I need.
I tried to use lxml and Pandas (read_xml), where both do what I would expect but not what I need exactly.
I have the following example XML:
<Errors>
    <Amount>3</Amount>
    <Error>
        <Code>405</Code>
        <Information>
            <Count>1</Count>
            <Time>16:18:13</Time>
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par1" Value="0"/>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par2" Value="1"/>
            </Parameter>
        </Information>
        <Information>
            <Count>2</Count>
            <Time>11:04:54</Time>
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par1" Value="2"/>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par2" Value="3"/>
            </Parameter>
        </Information>
    </Error>
    <Error>
        <Code>404</Code>
        <Information>
            <Count>1</Count>
            <Time>20:42:48</Time>
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par1" Value="4"/>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par2" Value="5"/>
            </Parameter>
        </Information>
    </Error>
</Errors>

I have the root Errors, where I can see that there are three errors in total: two times error 405 and one time error 404. Each error contains the time and some parameters. The parameter tags are always the same, but the values may differ.
Now I want a dataframe that looks like this:

My question is: how to do this properly?
I first tried the use of indices (root0[2] etc.), but that doesn't seem very efficient. Then I tried to use the texts itself (Code, Information, Count, Time..etc.), but I have no idea how to do that.
Hopefully someone knows how to do this.

Your xml isn’t valid, the closing tag must be Parameters instead of Parameter!

If you xml is valid, you can parse like:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

xml = """<Errors>
    <Amount>3</Amount>
    <Error>
        <Code>405</Code>
        <Information>
            <Count>1</Count>
            <Time>16:18:13</Time>
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par1" Value="0"/>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par2" Value="1"/>
            </Parameters>
        </Information>
        <Information>
            <Count>2</Count>
            <Time>11:04:54</Time>
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par1" Value="2"/>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par2" Value="3"/>
            </Parameters>
        </Information>
    </Error>
    <Error>
        <Code>404</Code>
        <Information>
            <Count>1</Count>
            <Time>20:42:48</Time>
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par1" Value="4"/>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par2" Value="5"/>
            </Parameters>
        </Information>
    </Error>
</Errors>"""

f=StringIO(xml)

root = ET.parse(f).getroot()

data = []
columns = ['code', 'count', 'time', 'Par1', 'Par2']
for err in root.findall("./Error"):
    code = err.find("./Code").text 
    for info in err.iter():
        if info.tag == "Count":
            count = info.text
        if info.tag == "Time":
            time = info.text         
        if info.tag =="Parameters":
            t =[]
            for p in info.findall('./Parameter'):
                at = (p.attrib['Parameter'], p.attrib['Value'])
                t.append(at)
            d = code, count, time, t[0][1], t[1][1]
            data.append(d)
            
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
print(df)

Output:
  code count      time Par1 Par2
0  405     1  16:18:13    0    1
1  405     2  11:04:54    2    3
2  404     1  20:42:48    4    5


Thanks! In this code the parameters are fixed, so if I add another parameter I have to update the code again. Is there a way to check for the parameters by itself and taking the parameter names as the columns?

You can use beautifulsoup to parse the XML to dataframe:
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_text = """\
<Errors>
    <Amount>3</Amount>
    <Error>
        <Code>405</Code>
        <Information>
            <Count>1</Count>
            <Time>16:18:13</Time>
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par1" Value="0"/>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par2" Value="1"/>
            </Parameter>
        </Information>
        <Information>
            <Count>2</Count>
            <Time>11:04:54</Time>
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par1" Value="2"/>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par2" Value="3"/>
            </Parameter>
        </Information>
    </Error>
    <Error>
        <Code>404</Code>
        <Information>
            <Count>1</Count>
            <Time>20:42:48</Time>
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par1" Value="4"/>
                <Parameter Parameter="Par2" Value="5"/>
            </Parameter>
        </Information>
    </Error>
</Errors>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_text, "xml")

data = []
for error in soup.select("Error"):
    for info in error.select("Information"):
        data.append(
            {
                "Code": error.Code.text,
                "Count": info.Count.text,
                "Time": info.Time.text,
                **{p["Parameter"]: p["Value"] for p in info.select("Parameter")},
            }
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

Prints:
  Code Count      Time Par1 Par2
0  405     1  16:18:13    0    1
1  405     2  11:04:54    2    3
2  404     1  20:42:48    4    5


The OP asked also for the time, what’s in your answer still missing! Also the xml is invalid!

@Hermann12 Added the Time

Thanks! In the bigger file I have different roots, how can I select the correct root?

@GaneshGebhard You can use .select_one() or .find() to find correct element that you will use as root. In my example I'm using soup as root.

Consider a single line Python by using XSLT, the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files, such as flattening XML for a pandas DataFrame. With lxml (default pandas XML parser), you can run XSLT 1.0 scripts in Python and effortlessly with stylesheet argument in pandas.read_xml. No for loops, if logic, or list.append!
XSLT (save below as an .xsl file, a special .xml file)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <data>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::Parameters"/>
    </data>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Parameters">
    <row>
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Error/Code"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Information/Count"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Information/Time"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Parameter"/>
    </row>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Parameter">
    <xsl:element name="{@Parameter}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Online Demo (click transform)
Python
errors_df = pd.read_xml(path_or_buffer="input.xml", stylesheet="style.xsl")

